# Error en un formulario que conecta a una base de datos en phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html

Todo va bien, pero al momento que oprimo el botón guardar me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function guardar() on a non-object
>   in C:\wamp\www\formulario\formulario.php on line 18.

Les dejo los códigos:

```
<?php
include ('libreria/motor.php');
$regis = Registros::mostrar();
$registros=new Registros();

if ($_POST){

    //$registros ->ID=$_POST['ID'];
    $registros ->Nombre=$_POST['txtNombre'];
    $registros ->No_control=$_POST['txtNoControl'];
    $registros ->Sexo=$_POST['txtSexo'];
    $registros ->Direccion=$_POST['txtDireccion'];
    $registros ->Correo=$_POST['txtCorreoElectronico'];
    $registros ->Telefono=$_POST['txtTelefono'];
    $registros ->Celular=$_POST['txtCelular'];
    $registros ->Carrera=$_POST['txtCarrera'];
    $registros ->Pocedencia=$_POST['txtEscuela'];
    $Registros ->guardar();
    header("Location:formulario.php");
}


?>
<html>
 <head>
<title>INSTITUTO TECNOLOGICO DE ALTAMIRA</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form method= "post" action="">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>REGISTRO DE ESTUDIANTES</legend>
       <table>
           <tr>
              <td>Nombre:
                <input type="text" name="txtNombre"/>
              </td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>No Control:
                   <input type="text" name="txtNoControl"/>
                 </td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Sexo:
                        <input type="radio" name="txtSexo" value="Femenino" />Femenino
                        <input type="radio" name="txtSexo" value="Masculino" />Masculino
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Direccion:
                          <input type="text" name="txtDireccion"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                         <tr>
                          <td>Correo Electronico:
                            <input type="text" name="txtCorreoElectronico"/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                             <tr>
                               <td>Telefono:
                                  <input type="text" name="txtTelefono"/>
                               </td>
                             </tr>
                              <tr>
                               <td>Celular:
                                   <input type="text" name="txtCelular"/>
                               </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Carrera:
                                  <select name="txtCarrera">
                                    <option>Agronomia</option>
                                    <option>Administracion</option>
                                    <option>Biologia</option>
                                    <option>Industrial</option>
                                    <option>Sistemas</option>
                                  </select>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Escuela De Pocedencia:
                                  <select name="txtEscuela">
                                    <option>ABRAHAM LINCOLN</option>
                                    <option>Cbtis105</option>
                                    <option>Cetis78</option>
                                    <option>CONALEP</option>
                                    <option>ITACE ALTAMIRA</option>
                                    <option>PREPA ALTAMIRA</option>
                                  </select>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                 <button method="post" type="submit">Agregar</button>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

       </table>
</fieldset>
<hr>

<fieldset>
 <legend>ALUMNOS REGISTRADOS</legend>

    <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>  
           <th>NOMBRE</th>
           <th>No DE CONTROL </th>
           <th>SEXO</th>
           <th>DIRECCION</th>
           <th>CORREO ELECTRONICO</th>
           <th>TELEFONO</th>
           <th>CELULAR</th>
           <th>CARRERA</th>
           <th>ESCUELA DE PROCEDENCIA</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

        foreach ($regis as $registros){
            echo"
            <tr>
            <td>$registros[ID]</td>
            <td>$registros[Nombre]</td>
            <td>$registros[No_control]</td>
            <td>$registros[Sexo]</td>
            <td>$registros[Direccion]</td>
            <td>$registros[Correo]</td>
            <td>$registros[Telefono]</td>
            <td>$registros[Celular]</td>
            <td>$registros[Carrera]</td>
            <td>$registros[Procedencia]</td>

            </tr>
            ";
        }
        ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</fieldset>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

CLASE REGISTROS.PHP

```
class registros {
    public $ID;
    public $Nombre;
    public $No_control;
    public $Sexo;
    public $Direccion;
    public $Correo;
    public $Telefono;
    public $Celular;
    public $Carrera;
    public $Procedencia;

    function guardar(){
        $sql=" insert  into registros (Nombre,No_control,Sexo,Direccion,Correo,Telefono,Celular,Carrera,Procedencia);
        values('($this=>Nombre)','($this=>No_control)','($this=>Sexo)','($this=>Direccion)','($this=>Correo)','($this=>Telefono)','($this=>Celular)','($this=>Carrera)','($this=>Procedencia)')";


        mysql_query($sql);


    }
    static function mostrar(){
        $sql="select * from registros";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql);
        $regis=array();
        while($fila=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)>0){
            $regis[]=$fila;
        }
    return $regis;
```

CLASE conexion.php

```
<?php

class Conexion{
    public $enlace;
    function __construct(){
        $this -> enlace=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this -> enlace);



    }
    function __destruct(){

        mysql_close($this->enlace);
    }



}
```

Comment: Por favor, si Alberto Mier ha solucionado tu problema, marca su respuesta como válida para cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP` es case-sensitive, por lo que el error esta aqui:

```
$Registros ->guardar();
```

Lo has puesto con mayuscula cuando lo has inicializado con minuscula:

```
$registros=new Registros();
```

Debes ponerlo en minuscula

Comment: muchas gracias amigo,no observe eso,ademas que tenia otro problema,saludos